# Do conditional breakpoints support lambdas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I would like to set a conditional breakpoint to break when the property `IsDone` evaluates to true. `IsDone` is defined as follows:

```
virtual public bool IsDone => Operations.All(o => o.IsComplete);
```

However, when I set `IsDone` as the condition on a breakpoint, I receive this error: "The condition for a breakpoint failed to execute... a common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate."

Can you explain why this is not supported?

[image]

Comment: My guess: The VS Debugger folks tried to do this, it wouldn't work, so they took the feature out and replaced it with that message box.  The debugger does a lot of _magic_ (injecting code, playing thread tricks, etc.), but sometimes, getting something to work just doesn't happen.